# Bootstrap v4: Scroll to the Tab Content div on click of Tab navigation item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the below Tabbable content with `nav-item` & `tab-content`:

```
<nav>
 <div class="nav nav-tabs my-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-buy" data-toggle="tab" href="#navBuy" role="tab" aria-controls="navBuy" aria-selected="true">Buy</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-rent" data-toggle="tab" href="#navRent" role="tab" aria-controls="navRent" aria-selected="false">Rent</a>
 </div>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
 <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="navBuy" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-buy">Buy property</div>
 <div class="tab-pane fade" id="navRent" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-rent">Rent property</div>
</div>
```

The above `Tabs` are the bottom of the Above the Fold and `tab-content` is in the Below the Fold.

Tried below jQuery code to scroll to the tab-content when nav-item is clicked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.my-tabs>li a').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.tab-content').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});

});
```

However, this jQuery code is not working and pages is not scrolling on click.

Comment: It work. http://jsfiddle.net/9w0pnh6d/

Comment: But it is not working with BootStrap framework. Check this I have added BS library to this http://jsfiddle.net/kingBethal/9w0pnh6d/1/